# Jenkins pipeline shell cut command with output redirection

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Today I faced an issue when was writing pipeline scenario. Look at the part of the script:

```
stage("test-stage") {
    steps {
        script {
            def srcFile = "test.txt"
            def dstFile ="test.txt.gz"
            sh "gzip ${srcFile} > ${dstFile}"  
        } 
    }
}
```

As result executed just a part of command before '>' (redirect output) sign: `+gzip test.txt`. How it is processing this symbol and how to figure out this issue? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit confusing that Jenkins doesn't log the whole command. But it's the way that you invoke gzip that is causing the problem. You could use this instead:

```
sh "cat ${srcFile} | gzip > ${dstFile}"
```

Comment: it works, but jenkins still doesn't log whole command. It logs command until '>'. I think that it's some kind of bug or maybe specific behavior.